# Mysql: How to call sql script file from other sql script file?

Tags: sql, mysql, file, call, sql-scripts

Suppose I have wrote script Table_ABC.sql which creates table ABC. I have created many such scripts for each of required tables. Now i want to write a script that call all of these script files in a sequence so basically I want another script file createTables.sql. Mysql provides option to execute a script file from "mysql" shell application but could find some command like **exec c:/myscripts/mytable.sql**. Please tell me if there is any command that can be written in sql script itself to call other one in latest mysql versions or alternative for same.

Thanks

Comment: I assume there is some reason why you can't just put all your SQL files into one and run that?

Comment: I am creating one script for each table better structuring and better management.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use [`source`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/batch-commands.html) command. So your script will be something like:

```
use your_db;
source script/s1.sql;
source script/s2.sql;
-- so on, so forth
```

Comment: I had already gone through this page. source command run on mysql application but i want to run it on mysql workbench's query analyzer tool.  Thanks

Comment: is it possible to give relative path of script files with respect to file that is contain these commands.

Comment: The mysql workbench displays error "SOURCE (source) is not valid input at this position".

Comment: This is the same error as in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45227599/mysql-syntax-error-source-source-is-not-valid-input-at-this-position