# MySQL query calling other SQL files to execute in order

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, hibernate

so I have a Java EE application and I use hibernate.
I have created import.sql file which is loaded each time i start the application.

My issue is that the database is quite big, so I have the startup data prepared in separate sql files, which I should load in certain order.

**So within this SQL script file i need to CALL or IMPORT or LOAD other SQL files in folder above this one (path is not a problem).**

I would be grateful for the solution for mySQL and maybe oracle db as well (but mysql is more important atm).

[This solution is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029240/mysql-how-to-call-sql-script-file-from-other-sql-script-file)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the thing is that for the moment it is not possible to load other QUERY SCRIPT files in one another. It could be raw data with [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html), but otherwise it is not possible.