# MySQL : syntax error : 'source' (source) is not valid input at this position

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

```
--  Sample employee database 
--  See changelog table for details
--  Copyright (C) 2007,2008, MySQL AB
--  
--  Original data created by Fusheng Wang and Carlo Zaniolo
--  http://www.cs.aau.dk/TimeCenter/software.htm
--  http://www.cs.aau.dk/TimeCenter/Data/employeeTemporalDataSet.zip
-- 
--  Current schema by Giuseppe Maxia 
--  Data conversion from XML to relational by Patrick Crews
-- 
-- This work is licensed under the 
-- Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 3.0 Unported License. 
-- To view a copy of this license, visit 
-- http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/ or send a letter to 
-- Creative Commons, 171 Second Street, Suite 300, San Francisco, 
-- California, 94105, USA.
-- 
--  DISCLAIMER
--  To the best of our knowledge, this data is fabricated, and
--  it does not correspond to real people. 
--  Any similarity to existing people is purely coincidental.
-- 

DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS employees;
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS employees;
USE employees;

SELECT 'CREATING DATABASE STRUCTURE' as 'INFO';

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dept_emp,
                     dept_manager,
                     titles,
                     salaries, 
                     employees, 
                     departments;

/*!50503 set default_storage_engine = InnoDB */;
/*!50503 select CONCAT('storage engine: ', @@default_storage_engine) as INFO */;

CREATE TABLE employees (
    emp_no      INT             NOT NULL,
    birth_date  DATE            NOT NULL,
    first_name  VARCHAR(14)     NOT NULL,
    last_name   VARCHAR(16)     NOT NULL,
    gender      ENUM ('M','F')  NOT NULL,    
    hire_date   DATE            NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (emp_no)
);

CREATE TABLE departments (
    dept_no     CHAR(4)         NOT NULL,
    dept_name   VARCHAR(40)     NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (dept_no),
    UNIQUE  KEY (dept_name)
);

CREATE TABLE dept_manager (
   emp_no       INT             NOT NULL,
   dept_no      CHAR(4)         NOT NULL,
   from_date    DATE            NOT NULL,
   to_date      DATE            NOT NULL,
   FOREIGN KEY (emp_no)  REFERENCES employees (emp_no)    ON DELETE CASCADE,
   FOREIGN KEY (dept_no) REFERENCES departments (dept_no) ON DELETE CASCADE,
   PRIMARY KEY (emp_no,dept_no)
); 

CREATE TABLE dept_emp (
    emp_no      INT             NOT NULL,
    dept_no     CHAR(4)         NOT NULL,
    from_date   DATE            NOT NULL,
    to_date     DATE            NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (emp_no)  REFERENCES employees   (emp_no)  ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (dept_no) REFERENCES departments (dept_no) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (emp_no,dept_no)
);

CREATE TABLE titles (
    emp_no      INT             NOT NULL,
    title       VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL,
    from_date   DATE            NOT NULL,
    to_date     DATE,
    # FOREIGN KEY (emp_no) REFERENCES employees (emp_no) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (emp_no,title, from_date)
); 

/*!50130
ALTER TABLE titles
partition by range (to_days(from_date))
(
    partition p01 values less than (to_days('1985-12-31')),
    partition p02 values less than (to_days('1986-12-31')),
    partition p03 values less than (to_days('1987-12-31')),
    partition p04 values less than (to_days('1988-12-31')),
    partition p05 values less than (to_days('1989-12-31')),
    partition p06 values less than (to_days('1990-12-31')),
    partition p07 values less than (to_days('1991-12-31')),
    partition p08 values less than (to_days('1992-12-31')),
    partition p09 values less than (to_days('1993-12-31')),
    partition p10 values less than (to_days('1994-12-31')),
    partition p11 values less than (to_days('1995-12-31')),
    partition p12 values less than (to_days('1996-12-31')),
    partition p13 values less than (to_days('1997-12-31')),
    partition p14 values less than (to_days('1998-12-31')),
    partition p15 values less than (to_days('1999-12-31')),
    partition p16 values less than (to_days('2000-12-31')),
    partition p17 values less than (to_days('2001-12-31')),
    partition p18 values less than (to_days('2002-12-31')),
    partition p19 values less than (to_days('3000-12-31'))
) */;


CREATE TABLE salaries (
    emp_no      INT             NOT NULL,
    salary      INT             NOT NULL,
    from_date   DATE            NOT NULL,
    to_date     DATE            NOT NULL,
    # FOREIGN KEY (emp_no) REFERENCES employees (emp_no) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (emp_no, from_date)
); 

/*!50130
ALTER TABLE salaries
partition by range (to_days(from_date))
(
    partition p01 values less than (to_days('1985-01-01')),
    partition p02 values less than (to_days('1986-01-01')),
    partition p03 values less than (to_days('1987-01-01')),
    partition p04 values less than (to_days('1988-01-01')),
    partition p05 values less than (to_days('1989-01-01')),
    partition p06 values less than (to_days('1990-01-01')),
    partition p07 values less than (to_days('1991-01-01')),
    partition p08 values less than (to_days('1992-01-01')),
    partition p09 values less than (to_days('1993-01-01')),
    partition p10 values less than (to_days('1994-01-01')),
    partition p11 values less than (to_days('1995-01-01')),
    partition p12 values less than (to_days('1996-01-01')),
    partition p13 values less than (to_days('1997-01-01')),
    partition p14 values less than (to_days('1998-01-01')),
    partition p15 values less than (to_days('1999-01-01')),
    partition p16 values less than (to_days('2000-01-01')),
    partition p17 values less than (to_days('2001-01-01')),
    partition p18 values less than (to_days('2001-02-01')),
    partition p19 values less than (to_days('2001-03-01')),
    partition p20 values less than (to_days('2001-04-01')),
    partition p21 values less than (to_days('2001-05-01')),
    partition p22 values less than (to_days('2001-06-01')),
    partition p23 values less than (to_days('2001-07-01')),
    partition p24 values less than (to_days('2001-08-01')),
    partition p25 values less than (to_days('2001-09-01')),
    partition p26 values less than (to_days('2001-10-01')),
    partition p27 values less than (to_days('2001-11-01')),
    partition p28 values less than (to_days('2001-12-01')),
    partition p29 values less than (to_days('2002-01-01')),
    partition p30 values less than (to_days('2002-02-01')),
    partition p31 values less than (to_days('2002-03-01')),
    partition p32 values less than (to_days('2002-04-01')),
    partition p33 values less than (to_days('2002-05-01')),
    partition p34 values less than (to_days('2002-06-01')),
    partition p35 values less than (to_days('2002-07-01')),
    partition p36 values less than (to_days('2002-08-01')),
    partition p37 values less than (to_days('2002-09-01')),
    partition p38 values less than (to_days('2002-10-01')),
    partition p39 values less than (to_days('2002-11-01')),
    partition p40 values less than (to_days('2002-12-01')),
    partition p41 values less than (to_days('3000-01-01'))
)
*/;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW dept_emp_latest_date AS
    SELECT emp_no, MAX(from_date) AS from_date, MAX(to_date) AS to_date
    FROM dept_emp
    GROUP BY emp_no;

# shows only the current department for each employee
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW current_dept_emp AS
    SELECT l.emp_no, dept_no, l.from_date, l.to_date
    FROM dept_emp d
        INNER JOIN dept_emp_latest_date l
        ON d.emp_no=l.emp_no AND d.from_date=l.from_date AND l.to_date = d.to_date;

flush /*!50503 binary */ logs;

SELECT 'LOADING departments' as 'INFO';
source load_departments.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING employees' as 'INFO';
source load_employees.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING dept_emp' as 'INFO';
source load_dept_emp.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING dept_manager' as 'INFO';
source load_dept_manager.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING titles' as 'INFO';
source load_titles.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING salaries' as 'INFO';
source load_salaries1.dump ;
source load_salaries2.dump ;
source load_salaries3.dump ;

source show_elapsed.sql ;
```

I'm a newbie. I'm downloading a huge mysql database sample for learning purposes. Using mysql workbench, when i open above script, it will highlight all the 'source load_******.dump;' statements, with the error 'syntax error:'source'(source) is not valid input at this position'. Can someone help me with this problem.

Btw, I download this database from: https://github.com/datacharmer/test_db

Comment: Well do those `.dump` files actually exist?  The `source` command tells MySQL to load a SQL script from that file.  If you have those files locally, perhaps you need to change the path to where they are actually located.

Comment: yup, they are exist, downloaded along with the script file

Comment: But are you sure that you have the right path/location?

Comment: I read the readme file, it doesn't say anything about changing the path/location. Everything are in the same folder.

Comment: [Read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968287/how-to-find-the-mysql-data-directory-from-command-line-in-windows).  I can't give you an exact answer without sitting at your MySQL Workbench, but my hunch is that MySQL is looking in a location for those `.dump` files where nothing is there.  Make the files visible to MySQL and the script should run.  The readme doesn't have to tell you this, if it expects you to know how MySQL works.

Answer (score 6):

You can run the script using `MySQL Workbench`.

Go to **File** -> **Run SQL Script...**

[image]

Select the file(*.sql) you want to run. Then you see the screen as below.

[image]

Hit **Run** button. It creates schema and imports tables and data as per the script.

Answer (score 4):

The `source` command is not a MySQL statement, but something only handled by the MySQL client. MySQL Workbench does not handle this (as it is focused on pure MySQL code).

To import the entire set remove the source commands from the main file and then manually import these files like you did with the main dump. A bit tedious, but at least a way to load all files.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the following lines because its trying to import other files

```
SELECT 'LOADING departments' as 'INFO';
source load_departments.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING employees' as 'INFO';
source load_employees.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING dept_emp' as 'INFO';
source load_dept_emp.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING dept_manager' as 'INFO';
source load_dept_manager.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING titles' as 'INFO';
source load_titles.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING salaries' as 'INFO';
source load_salaries1.dump ;
source load_salaries2.dump ;
source load_salaries3.dump ;

source show_elapsed.sql ;
```

Or import from commend line

```
mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql
```

Make sure the following files should be in same folder

```
load_departments.dump 
load_employees.dump 
load_dept_emp.dump 
load_dept_manager.dump 
load_titles.dump 
load_salaries1.dump 
load_salaries2.dump 
load_salaries3.dump 
show_elapsed.sql
```

Comment: I believe I cannot remove the lines because I do want to import the files that contain the data for all the table in the database. All the file are in the same folder. I've done some experiments and I believe all the script run correctly except for the 'source load_xxxx.dump' line. Is there anything wrong with the syntax?

Comment: if you are running, for example your folder `/home/sql/` update the file path of `sql` and `dump` also

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue today as well. After trying all the above methods and still meeting errors, I decided to download the older MySQL Workbench version, and it worked all well!

Current latest version: 8.0.24
My downloaded version: 8.0.20

Still don't know why it worked.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and I solved by watching this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ksz8J6FQ0A

Basically, you can use the command prompt to install employees database :)